# How to improve this source code quoting?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I posted an answer including source code with a method I regularly used here and on web pages:

> [Corruptions within Calendar: duplicates. How to analyse their cause and fix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206843/22003)

My (stackexchange) source (of this source code) is:

```
    <pre>
    $ cat <<'eof' >duplicate.pl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    </pre>
```

and the result obtained, is:

```
    $ cat duplicate.pl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
```

Which is wrong in term of displayed text and in term of working answer, since the shell script is not working. 
I'm not able to present the problem here through the use of `<pre>` and
used a lot of `return` and spaces to achieve a presentable explanation.

---

What is the easiest way to insert source code with just one enclosing
markup?

What did I do wrong to not being able to get a correct behaviour of a basic `<pre>` markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try :-)

```
$ cat <<'eof' >duplicate.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Ok so far? Or is there any special meaning of using `<pre>` tags?

The easiest way to format larger blocks of code is to just paste the code into the edit window, select the whole code block and the click on the code formatter (**{}**) at the top of the edit window.

See also the help pages on supported markdown formatting (especially the second screenshot below) and [this question on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks):

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Is there any special meaning of using `<pre>` tags?" Yes. It's pretty simple and standard. For me I nearly type it automatically when including code. Hence I never imagined I would need any button to perform such a basic markup.(missing return) To give you an example in another field which is boring me to great deepths, I would never look for a button which would permit me to put a [return] :).

Comment: You don't need to use the button, you can just prepend 4 space characters on every line. But for long blocks of code, using the button may be easier, especially if you paste whole scripts into the edit window.

Comment: I don't like the prepend trick: too slow, and too error prone. Honestly I don't find anything simpler than a plain `<pre>`…`</pre>` :(.

Comment: Let me try to formulate my thoughts it in a way to make something useful: would it be possible, easy, to make standard `<pre>`…`</pre>` or `<code>`...`</code>` work?

Comment: I'm not a developer here :-) To make a feature request, you can always ask a new meta question, describe the functionality you are missing and add the `feature-request` tag. Might take a few days till somebody from the SE team answers.

Comment: For this one I would also search meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow You won't have been the first to see this

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or is

[image]

not just the same as selecting the block & hitting  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>K</kbd>  ?

Prior to discovering that I used to add extra indents in a text editor & paste it over, which was a tad irritating...

---

Unformatted

$ cat <<'eof' >duplicate.pl

## !/usr/bin/perl

Using `<pre> </pre>`

```
$ cat duplicate.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>K</kbd>

```
$ cat <<'eof' >duplicate.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Using `{}`

```
$ cat <<'eof' >duplicate.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
```