# Why doesn't 'code' formatting seem to work for me?

Tags: support

I seem to regularly have problems adding `code` to my answers so that they're formatted properly, and I don't know if it's a bug, me, a combination of the two, or something else altogether.

By way of example, today I posted this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323172/168832). Now, in case I get it to appear properly, below is a screenshot of the portion as it currently displays:

[image]

As you can see it's not really displaying properly. I've tried following everything in [How to improve this source code quoting?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2626/168832), but often the result is the same.

I've also tested this using different hardware, software and operating systems.

What am I doing wrong?

This is happening all too often, but I'm not flagging it as a *bug* yet because I figure it must be working okay for others.

Comment: Multiline code formatting works better if you use four or eight space characters instead of `` ;-)

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by "display properly"?

Comment: @patrix Thanks for editing the answer I posted earlier - that's exactly what I meant by *display properly*. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is the proper way to include blocks of code within a numbered or bulleted list: use [*eight* spaces instead of four](/editing-help#advanced-lists):

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
      <div>This is a test.</div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

See [Code blocks inside lists and/or list items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30059/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

---

Applied to your answer above you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :) Hopefully I'll never have this problem again! LOL